# Why does the greater than sign of the arrow function turn red when Vue TS is used

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code

[image]
[image]
Vscode enables "editor.bracketpaircolorization When "enabled" and Vue TS is used, the greater than sign of the arrow function will turn red. It will not be like this if lang = "ts" is removed. It looks very uncomfortable

Comment: Have the same issue since the latest vscode update. Hopefully it gets fixed soon.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a VSCode issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/157322

As mentioned in [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/157322#issuecomment-1211092343), a temporal solution meanwhile the issue is fixed is to exclude the `<` `>` pair from the [`colorizedBracketPairs`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/433e5f7ee4504e27ea283fefb72772aa4b698b2e/extensions/typescript-basics/language-configuration.json#L102).

Add the following to your [`settings.json`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson):

```json
"editor.language.colorizedBracketPairs": [
  ["{", "}"],
  ["[", "]"],
  ["(", ")"]
],
```